# How to include the setup description in Wix burn setup?

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.8

I have developed a WIX burn project and i don't want to have the license agreement in welcome window. Instead, i wish to include what is the purpose of this setup in one or two lines in welcome dialog? I have tried the below code(LicenseUrl="hai". This too displayed as a link).

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="" LogoFile="Logo.png" SuppressOptionsUI="yes" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
<Chain>
  <MsiPackage Id="NormaSetup" Name="Wixdata" SourceFile="..\..\Wix\NormaSetup\bin\Release\NormaSetup.msi" Permanent="no" ForcePerMachine="yes" Compressed="yes" Vital="yes" />
</Chain>
```

Could anyone please provde your suggestion on this to include the description about this setup in Burn setup UI(Welcome Window)?

Comment: @Rob Mensching, Could you please provide your suggestion on this? I need to display some text in the burn UI instead of license agreement.

Comment: Anyone can please share your suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: @Rob, i have referred the following site to include the welcome message in burn setup. But, when i integrate the code and check, msi installation is not started.. Am getting the below error.

Comment: Planned package: SyncfusionCISetup, state: Absent, default requested: Cache, ba requested: Cache, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
 Plan complete, result: 0x0
Apply begin
Launching elevated engine process.
Launched elevated engine process.
Connected to elevated engine.
Pausing automatic updates.
Paused automatic updates.
Creating a system restore point.
 System restore disabled, system restore point not created.